# How to batch convert to mp4 with arista-transcoder?

Tags: command-line, batch, transcode

I dont understand how to list valid preset names and select the `Computer - H.264` preset available in the `arista-gtk` listing.

When I batch convert like `arista-transcode -p "Computer - H.264" *.wmv` the files are created as .webm, I need mp4.

Answer (score 0):

the preset `H.264` appears to make mp4's:

```
arista-transcode -p "H.264" *.wmv
```